# "LineStrings must have at least 2 coordinate tuples" error in QGIS polygonize

Tags: qgis, polygonize

I am using QGIS version 2.18.9. I wanted to convert DXF into polygon. First, I used the tool called "v.in.dxf" under the processing tool. Using that tool, line shapefile was created. Then I ran the "v.clean.advanced" tool under the processing tool. Then output of that tool was used as the input to the polygonize tool. While running that "polygonize tool, the following error appeared:

> LineStrings must have at least 2 coordinate tuples See log for more details

Can any one explain this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our "Focused question / Best answer" model operates.  Please [Edit] your question to provide enough details to support an answer: The version of software in use, the exact inputs, the log contents...

Answer (score 3):

Your line layer has an error. There is at least one line with only a single point (lines must have at least two points), which is causing the polygonize tool to fail.

Run a check geometry on it and remove the offending lines.